# React TypeScript: Parameter "e" implicitly has an any type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

I keep getting this error, when I add this function to my onClick button:

```
const FirefoxBlockedModal = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const onBackClick = (e) => {
        navigate("/", { replace: true });
    };
    return (
                    <MenuButton
                        className={styles.goBackBtn}
                        classNameOnOver={styles.over}
                        classNameOnPressed={styles.pressed}
                        onClick={onBackClick}
                    >
                        <Trans>back</Trans>
                    </MenuButton>
    );
};

export default FirefoxBlockedModal;
```

Here are some pictures of the things I tried and the errors I get from typescript. What Should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, if you are not using the parameter just get rid of it `const onBackClick = () => `

Comment: If you want to keep the parameter and not use it, you can do this `const onBackClick = (_e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) =>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TSConfig file by default, doesn't implicitly allow the `any` type. you must declare it.

If you declare like this, you will not get this error:

```
const onBackClick = (e: any) => {
  navigate("/", { replace: true });
};
```

Comment: Why declare it as `any` when it has a narrower type?